# Polymer: Imperatively set property doesn't changes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm stuck for like two days now and I'm shooting blanks at this problem I'm about to describe.

I made a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OrUiqcFfb70VFtO06sNT

So, I have `<main-element>` - this element contains two children: `<child-element>` and `<sub-main>`. Both of these elements binds on `owner` object that is set in `<main-element>`. Like this:

`<child-element owner="{{owner}}"></child-element>`

Now, `<sub-main>` contains another element - `<sub-child-element>`.

```
<template>
    <sub-child-element id="sub"></sub-child-element>
</template>
```

But it binds `owner` property imperatively:

```
attached: function() {
    this.$.sub.owner = this.owner;
}
```

As you might have guessed `<sub-child-elements>` doesn't see changes made to `owner` object. I have tried to sprinkle `this.set` and `this.notifyPath` all over the place but it did not helped.

Any way to make this work? Is it even possible do do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could observe `owner` in `sub-main` like so.

```
observers: [
  'ownerChanged(owner.*)'
],
```

And whenever it changes, notify the `sub-child-element`.

```
  ownerChanged: function(event){
   this.$.sub.notifyPath(event.path, event.value);
  }
```

Here's a [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/PkQBJbstCIbqjBMwrMnV?p=preview) of your plunker that does this.

**Update**

You can also observe a specific path, such as `owner.details.location`. Just note that the argument to the handler will be the new value. For [deep path observation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#deep-observation) (such as `owner.*`) the handler receives a change record as arguments. 
So in your example, you could do it as follows.

```
observers: [
    'ownerChanged(owner.details.location)'
],

ownerChanged: function(newValue){
    this.$.sub.notifyPath("owner.details.location", newValue);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why `owner.*` works, while `owner.details.location` doesn't?

Comment: It will work, if you adapt the handler. Have a look at my updated answer.